# Photoshop brush cursors cropped at 82px

Tags: windows-7, photoshop-cs6

My brush cursors in Photoshop seem to getting cropped when 82px or larger, and it's difficult to paint without seeing the full preview size. See here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q4PW6.jpg

Any ideas? I'm using Photoshop CS6 on Windows 7.

Comment: I've Googled this as many different ways as I could think of, and finally found one lone result that seems to describe my scenario: http://www.clearps.com/photoshop-forum/index.php/t/77912/

Comment: I don't have NVidia graphics, only integrated Intel i5-2450M HD Graphics 3000, but I've updated those and the issue still remains. I'm getting a new computer soon, so I might just give up on this one.